# How to change directory from environment variable in tcsh?

Tags: environment-variables, cd-command, tcsh

I have captured a linux path into an environment variable. Now I want to change the directory to the path in that environment variable.

Lets say the environment variable is named: `gr`

- I can see the variable value if I use the command: `echo "$gr"`
- However when a try a similar syntax like this: `cd "$gr"`, the `cd` command drops me into my home folder instead of the intended action.

How can I use the `cd` command with an environment variable?

Comment: The command `cd "gr"` should work except for some corner cases for the value of `gr`. Could you say what is the value of `$gr`? Do you get a correct output from `ls -ld "$gr"` ?

Comment: Try use `pushd $gr` and if you are going to change the back directory, use `popd`.